# Remove <h3> by its text content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-heading

I am trying to remove a 'h3' tag from a header list selecting it by text.
For example if I have:

html:

```
<h3>NO CHANGE</h3>
<h3>h3 to be removed</h3>
<h3>NO CHANGE</h3>
<h3>NO CHANGE</h3>
<h3>NO CHANGE</h3>
```

jQuery:

```
var h3_text_remove = $('h3').text();
if (h3_text_remove == 'h3 to be removed'){
    $('h3').remove();
//console.log (h3_text_remove);
}
```

How can I remove just the header with text 'h3 to be removed'?

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/q2nb08t6/7/

Comment: You can use each for h3 tag and checked the text of h3 tag if matched with your condition. then remove the h3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** selector

```
$("h3:contains('h3 to be removed')").remove();
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2nb08t6/8/)**

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
//If text can have leading or trailing spaces
$('h3').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() == 'h3 to be removed';
}).remove();

//or if the text should match exactly:
$('h3').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'h3 to be removed';
}).remove();
```

**DEMO 1**

```js
$('h3').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() == 'h3 to be removed';
})
.remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>NO CHANGE</h3>
<h3>h3 to be removed</h3>
<h3>NO CHANGE</h3>
<h3>NO CHANGE</h3>
<h3>NO CHANGE</h3>
<h3>h3 to be removed </h3>
<h3> h3 to be removed</h3>
<h3>h3 to be removed xx</h3>
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/q2nb08t6/11/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one line using the `:contains()` selector:

```
$('h3:contains("h3 to be removed")').remove();
```

Or using a variable:

```
var h3_text_remove = $('#specificH3').text();
$('h3:contains("' + h3_text_remove + '")').remove();
```

Note that this will remove all `h3` elements which contain that text in any way, so both of the following would be removed:

```
<h3>h3 to be removed</h3>
<h3>foo h3 to be removed bar</h3>
```

To restrict it to elements containing the whole text only, use `filter()`:

```
$('h3').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'h3 to be removed';
}).remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this solution: basic solution to understand easily.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q2nb08t6/10/

```
$('h3').each(function(){
var h3_text_remove = $(this).text().trim();

if (h3_text_remove == 'h3 to be removed'){
    $(this).remove();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the tag and not the content

```
$('h3').each(function(){
    var h3_text_remove = $(this).text().trim();

    if (h3_text_remove == 'h3 to be removed'){
        $(this).unwrap();
    }
});
```